# Refresh table based on search result using AJAX in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to update table in MVC using ajax based on keyword in search textbox. I am able to send the data to the controller using ajax but not able to update the table in view based on result from controller method.

PS. Tried search and applied suggestions but nothing worked for me.

**Purchase.cshtml**

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="btnSearch" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
  </div>

//partial view
if (Model.purchases != null)
{
    @Html.Partial("_PurchaseList", Model);
}
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSearch').keyup(function () {
        var searchVal = $('#btnSearch').val();
        //alert(searchVal);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: "/Home/SearchPurchase/", // the method we are calling
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "DistributorName": searchVal
            }),
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (result) {
                //alert('Yay! It worked!');
                //location.reload();
            },
            error: function (result) {
                //alert('not worked :' + result.statusText);
            }
        });
    }); //btnsearch keyup finishes

});
</script>
```

**_PurchaseList.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<AEWebSite.Models.PurchaseModel>
<table class="table table-dark table-hover" id="myDataTable" style="border-radius:20px;">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GSTNumber)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DistributorName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InvoiceDate)
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GSTNumber)
        </td>
 <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item. DistributorName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceDate)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult SearchPurchase(PurchaseModel data)
{
        if (data != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.DistributorName))
        {
        var lstPurchase = aEEntities.Purchases.Where(a => a.DistributorName.Contains(data.DistributorName)).ToList();
            List<Models.PurchaseModel> modelObjPurchase = new List<Models.PurchaseModel>();
            foreach (var item in lstPurchase)
            {
                modelObjPurchase.Add(new Models.PurchaseModel { Id = item.Id, GSTNumber = item.GSTNumber, DistributorName = item.DistributorName, InvoiceDate = item.InvoiceDate, InvoiceNumber = item.InvoiceNumber, Total = item.Total });
            }
            return PartialView("_PurchaseList", modelObjPurchase);
        }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are making an ajax request, `SearchPurchase` method just returning a PartialView. When you call that partialView it will not find and update current partialView in your view. So you need to find and update your partialView after ajax request.

I have not tested but  I think this code will work for you:

surround your partial view with a div (to be able to find it with JS and replace it content)

```
if (Model.purchases != null)
{
    <div id="searchResult">
       @Html.Partial("_PurchaseList", Model);
    </div>
}
```

and success part of your ajax call:

```
    success: function (result) {
        //alert('Yay! It worked!');
        //location.reload();
        $("#searchResult").replaceWith( result );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#divId").html( result );